# CKEditor - Alignment

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I' trying to set up CKEditor options as in the following screenshoot:

[image]

Everythings works fine except the alignment buttons:

[image]

I saw that an issue (2649546) about this has been created but it seems that is still pending.

Any suggestions about how I could solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the Full Package of the CKEditor library.

You can download it at the [official website](http://ckeditor.com/download).